# Select rows with any infinite value (Inf or -Inf)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, infinity

How do I subset rows from a data frame which have at least one infinite value (`Inf` or `-Inf`)?

Here is an example data frame:

```
my_data <- data.frame(column1 = c(Inf, 5, 3,4,5), 
                      column2 = c(1, Inf, -Inf, NA, 33))
```

I tried:

```
my_data[rowSums(is.infinite(my_data)) > 0, ]
```

But got the error:

`Error in is.infinite(my_data) :  default method not implemented for type 'list'`

Which is suprising, as the `is.na()` equivalent works fine:

```
my_data[rowSums(is.na(my_data)) > 0, ]
```

I was able to find methods to change `Inf` values to `NA` but this is not quite what I am looking for, I only want to display all rows that contain and `Inf` or `-Inf` rather than replace them with `NA`.

EDIT: If there is method of doing this for a data frame with many columns, without individually typing out each column that would be ideal.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Regarding "Which is suprising", please see `?is.infinite` about argument `x`: " the default methods handle atomic vectors". Then see corresponding text for `?is.na`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `is.infinite` cannot apply on a data.frame. An alternative is `sapply`:

```r
my_data[rowSums(sapply(my_data, is.infinite)) > 0, ]

#   column1 column2
# 1     Inf       1
# 2       5     Inf
# 3       3    -Inf
```

---

With `dplyr`,you could use `if_any` or `if_all` to apply `is.infinite` to a selection of columns and combine the results into a single logical vector.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  filter(if_any(where(is.numeric), is.infinite))
```

Comment: Or `my_data[is.infinite(rowSums(my_data)), ]`

Comment: Thank you so much  Darren Tsai, your answer worked well, even if the dataframe had non-numeric columns! 

Henrik, thanks your answer works, but only if the entire data frame is numeric.
`Error in rowSums(my_data) : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @juliefoxsteven I thought your toy data was representative of your real data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- data.frame(column1 = c(Inf, 5, 3,4,5), 
                      column2 = c(1, Inf, -Inf, NA, 33))


my_data
#   column1 column2
# 1     Inf       1
# 2       5     Inf
# 3       3    -Inf
# 4       4      NA
# 5       5      33

my_data %>% 
  filter(is.infinite(column1) | is.infinite(column2))
#   column1 column2
# 1     Inf       1
# 2       5     Inf
# 3       3    -Inf
```

If you have too many columns to individually name, you could use `if_any()` (credit to [@RuiBarradas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247930/how-to-show-rows-with-values-of-infinity-inf-or-inf-in-r/73247966?noredirect=1#comment129360759_73247966)), like so:

```r
# Across all columns
my_data %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), is.infinite)) 

# Across a range of columns
my_data %>% 
  filter(if_any(column1:column2, is.infinite))
```

Comment: Hi stevec, thanks for the reply. That does work for my simple example. However, my actual dataset has over 100 columns, sorry I should have mentioned, will edit my original post.

Comment: @juliefoxsteven `my_data %>% filter(if_any(everything(), is.infinite))` applies `is.infinitee` to *all*  columns. To apply it to only some, change `everything()` to a columns selection.

Comment: @RuiBarradas very nice. I toyed around using `across()` but couldn't quite get it. Do you know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: @stevec `across` gives a warning, ```Warning message: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or `if_all()`.```

Comment: @RuiBarradas oh wow, I wasn't aware of that. Great info.

Comment: @stevec you could check my answer to see how to use `filter` + `if_any`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai very nice. Can I ask why the `where(is.numeric)` part?

Comment: @stevec `if_any()` defaults to apply `is.infinite` to all columns. `where(is.numeric)` make it only apply to numeric ones, and hence improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, [`help("is.infinite")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.finite.html), last paragraph of section Details:

> All three functions are generic: you can write methods to handle specific classes of objects, see [InternalMethods](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/InternalMethods.html).

So a solution is to write `.list` and `.data.frame` methods for `is.finite`, `is.infinite` and `is.nan`. But beware, if you use a system without these methods available, you will get the error in the question.

```r
is.finite.list <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.finite)
  x
}
is.finite.data.frame <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.finite)
  x
}
is.infinite.list <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.infinite)
  x
}
is.infinite.data.frame <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.infinite)
  x
}
is.nan.list <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.nan)
  x
}
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, base::is.nan)
  x
}

my_data <- data.frame(column1 = c(Inf, 5, 3,4,5), 
                      column2 = c(1, Inf, -Inf, NA, 33))

is.infinite(my_data)
#>   column1 column2
#> 1    TRUE   FALSE
#> 2   FALSE    TRUE
#> 3   FALSE    TRUE
#> 4   FALSE   FALSE
#> 5   FALSE   FALSE

is.finite(my_data)
#>   column1 column2
#> 1   FALSE    TRUE
#> 2    TRUE   FALSE
#> 3    TRUE   FALSE
#> 4    TRUE   FALSE
#> 5    TRUE    TRUE

is.nan(my_data)
#>   column1 column2
#> 1   FALSE   FALSE
#> 2   FALSE   FALSE
#> 3   FALSE   FALSE
#> 4   FALSE   FALSE
#> 5   FALSE   FALSE

# The question code line throwing the error
my_data[rowSums(is.infinite(my_data)) > 0, ]
#>   column1 column2
#> 1     Inf       1
#> 2       5     Inf
#> 3       3    -Inf
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>